# Matlab: how to plot 3D text ( not 2D as function text does)

Tags: matlab

I know it is not a trivial task however I was wondering if anyone has already done this:
the text(x,y,z,'text') function plots a 2d text attached to the coordinate system of the 2d figure. What I need is a 3D text as a 3D entity which changes in accordance with the camera view.

Or if there is a way to extract the 2D data (x,y) of a 2D text and transform it ( rotate + translate) in 3D coordinate system.
Thanks a lot in advance
PS. I only have matlab basic version, with no toolbox in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for [1].
1. http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/mupad/plot/PRIMITIV_Text3d.html

Comment: Thanks but didnt want to use toolboxes